# Vite does not detect changes when running from a subfolder

Tags: laravel, vite

We are migrating a large Laravel project from vue 2 to vue 3 and also want to adopt Vite in the process. In order to do that I need to run Laravel Mix with Vue 2 and Vite with Vue 3 alongside eachother. Because you can't run 2 version of Vue alongside eachother I have decided to move the Vite setup to a subfolder (./vite) and install the following dependencies there:

vite/package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "dev:hack": "watch 'vite build -m development --emptyOutDir' ../Modules/Filter",
    "build": "vite build --emptyOutDir"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.68.0"
  }
}
```

Using the following vite/vite.config.js:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
    build: {
        outDir: '../public/build'
    },
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['../Modules/Filter/Resources/assets/sass/app.scss', '../Modules/Filter/Resources/assets/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    // The Vue plugin will re-write asset URLs, when referenced
                    // in Single File Components, to point to the Laravel web
                    // server. Setting this to `null` allows the Laravel plugin
                    // to instead re-write asset URLs to point to the Vite
                    // server instead.
                    base: null,

                    // The Vue plugin will parse absolute URLs and treat them
                    // as absolute paths to files on disk. Setting this to
                    // `false` will leave absolute URLs un-touched so they can
                    // reference assets in the public directory as expected.
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ]
});
```

This works great when simply building the files, but when I run just Vite, no changes are detected.
I solved this with the dev:hack command, but this is very slow as a full build is done on every change.

The project is divided in modules located in the Modules folder. For now im just trying to get the Filter module to compile correctly, later on more Modules will be compiled.

The files that Vite has to watch are located here:
Modules/Filter/Resources/assets

And the files there get used in the Laravel Blade components located here:
Modules/Filter/Resources/views

I would like to use the Vite command to watch for file changes without the need of a full rebuild. But it simply does not detect changes. A build does work without issues which is what is so confusing to me.

Also it might just be that this aproach is not the best, if you have any suggestion on an alternative way for me to slowly migrate the project over, please do.

Here is a repo with a reproduction of the bug.
https://github.com/mve/vite-subfolder

Comment: What is the directory of `../Modules/Filter/Resources/assets/sass/app.scss` , can you  put your full relative path ?

Comment: Yes, the path for that file is just: `Modules/Filter/Resources/assets/sass/app.scss`

Comment: I also edited my question, I created a fresh install of Laravel and created the same setup showing what the problem is, feel free to check that out: https://github.com/mve/vite-subfolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that it's just not worth the hassle so I'm going to use the already existing Laravel Mix setup for building the code and just use Vue 2 for now.

I think an implementation like this just adds too much complexity.